# Getting a null pointer exception when trying to use an array to store multiple instances of the same object when creating a text-based 'database'

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, null

I'm trying to create a 'database' of text in java that takes user input to fill objects (movies) and stores them in an array in my database clas. 
Here is my 'Movie' class without all the 'sets' and 'gets':

```
public class Movie
{
     private int fileSize,duration;
     private String movieNamez,director;
     static int numberOfMovies;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
// constructor method
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public Movie()
   {
     movieNamez = "No title - SLOT FREE";
     director = "No director - SLOT FREE";
     fileSize = 0;
     duration = 0;
 }

 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    public void setmovieNumber(int movieNumber)
       {
           this.numberOfMovies = movieNumber;
       }
    public int getmovieNumber()
    {
        return this.numberOfMovies;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    public void setmovieName(String newmovieNamez)
    {
        this.movieNamez = newmovieNamez;
    }
    public String getmovieName()
    {
        return this.movieNamez;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the relevant part of my MovieDatabase class:

```
public class MovieDatabase
{


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   int maxMovies = 4;

  // ArrayList<Movie> allMovies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    Movie [] allMovies  = new Movie[maxMovies]; 
  //md.addmovieData(movieCount,movieName,director,fileSize,duration);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addmovieData(int movieNum, String movieName,String director, int fileSize, int duration)
    {
            allMovies[movieNum].setmovieName(movieName);
            allMovies[movieNum].setDirector(director);
            allMovies[movieNum].setfileSize(fileSize);
            allMovies[movieNum].setDuration(duration);

    }


    private void printMovie(Movie movie){
        System.out.println("Movie Name: "+movie.getmovieName());
        System.out.println("Movie Director: "+movie.getDirector());
        System.out.println("Movie File Size: "+movie.getfileSize());
        System.out.println("Movie Duration: "+movie.getDuration());
        System.out.println();
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And lastly here are the lines in the user interface class where input is taken and sent to the database (to then be sent to the movie object).

```
 MovieDatabase md = new MovieDatabase();
int movieCount=0
  md.addmovieData(movieCount,movieName,director,fileSize,duration);
                             movieCount++;
```

I'm trying to send the info to be stored in as a movie object along with an integer that tells me the count of movies, then as movieCount iterated I'm using that iteration to tell the program which number (place) in the array the movie should be stored under. Something is wrong with my method of implementing the arrays so I'm getting a null pointer exception, but after hours (shameful, i know) of fiddling with it and trying other methods (including arrayList) I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for your time guys, this is doing my head in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an Array object, all it's states gets initialised to default values, which in your case is null.

In `addmovieData` method, you have to first create a `Movie` object and push it to `allMovies`. Something like this -

```
Movie movie = new Movie();
allMovies[movieNum] = movie;
allMovies[movieNum].setmovieName(movieName);
allMovies[movieNum].setDirector(director);
allMovies[movieNum].setfileSize(fileSize);
allMovies[movieNum].setDuration(duration);
```

Comment: Thanks!! That now allows me to add a movie, however I'm still getting a null pointer exception when I try to use my printmovie method, but if I try to solve it by creating a new movie like last time it (obviously)prints a new, blank movie instead of the movie I just added. Again, thanks for taking the time to help me. Here is the code that prints it:



'public void printDatabase()
    {
        
        for (int i=0; i<allMovies.length; i++){
        printMovie(allMovies[i]);
    }

    }' and printMovie is alread included in my original question.

Comment: @rodney1234 It could be because your `allMovies` has less `Movie`s than `allMovies.length`? You should either add a null check in `printMovie` method (`if (movie != null) { //print movie }`), or call `printMovie` only `movieCount` times (i.e, `for (int i = 0; i < movieCount; i++)`)